# Virtualbox on Ubuntu /Windows XP viruses or security issues?

Tags: virtualbox

I wanna install Windows XP in a Virtualbox on Ubuntu 13.10, I will install it only for being able to use a programs of the government for inputting taxes ( the Argentine government hasn't make programs for Linux yet) ,it doesn't use internet, I'd like to generate the file and then send it trought internet but from Ubuntu; and play Pes 2011 (it doesn't use internet too) . Do I need to install an antivirus or anything else in Windows? I'm afraid viruses can infect Ubuntu,though I won't use internet from Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XP is rather outdated, and not as secure as newer versions.It is also EOL in 2014, and you will not be getting security updates after that. While having AV is usually a good idea, a virus that affects your VM is unlikely to affect your main system in the current state of things. Crossplatform VMs are rare.

However, to be safe, I'd probably get the XP system set up and up to date, then *snapshot* it. That way, you can roll back to a system which has a known state of being virus free. This would leave you the option of using a non resident malware protection like malwarebytes rather than a resident protection like MSSE (which I'd recommend). I'd also work as a limited user if possible since the reduced permissions means better security - it limits the damage a virus running under your account can do.

You could probably run the tax software in windows, print it with a PDF printer, and send the pdf to ubuntu to print via a shared folder.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu vulnerabilities come from outdated programs. If you keep your computer up to date your system will be more secure. A virus* in Windows VM can not affect Ubuntu.

You can't play games like Pes2011 in virtualBox, but you can [install Pes 2011 in Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=21569&iTestingId=57825). Also you should try to run your taxes programs in [Wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine) and [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/es/) first.

Comment: Thank you! I tried taxes programs in wine,they run ok,but I can't print,don't know why,and thought VB could help, although I dont know how to send files from Ubuntu to Windows VM,and why can't games be played in VB?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders

Comment: You need to use shared folder to share data between ubuntu and Windows VM. Here is a list of working games in virtual box http://virtualbox-gaming.wikia.com/wiki/Working_games . I don't know about the trouble with the printer maybe you should post another question.